# Acrobat Javascript that fills out form and saves it to one of many folders

Tags: javascript, acrobat

**EDIT: I solved my issue with help from a different forum. It was my variables and how I never let the while loop define them, I had only declared them at the top so the loop just saw it as a constant value which was the first record being imported.**

So, I'm trying to fill in an Acrobat PDF form I made with information in a txt file and then save it to one of a number of folders according to information in the form. I have a series of folders setup named after number ranges (i.e. 1-49, 50-99, 100-149, etc.) and some of the folders are preceded by the letter "z" because our numbering system for what we're tracking with these forms includes some names formatted with a Z at the end ( the people here before me kinda suck).

The logic of the code I'm trying to correct is such (if you just want to see the code it's below):

import text data within a while loop -> use indexOf to search the target field value for the letter Z -> use switch to setup 2 blocks of code, 1 for values that contain "z" and 1 for values without "z" -> determine which code block to run based on the "z"  -> use substr(0,3) to pull the first three characters from the value and use that in the code blocks to compare to our number ranges to see which range the number falls in -> set a variable with a string according to which range it falls in (i.e. "100-149/") -> go to save the PDF -> use the previously set variable to amend the output directory of saveAs to which ever range it switched our variable to and save the PDF in the corresponding folder named as the number range -> increment a variable and repeat the loop

My problem now is that the variable we're setting with the switch code is coming out as just a zero. So instead of adding my string and making it create the PDFs in the correct subfolders, it just adds a 0 to the beginning of the file name and saves it in the top level folder. I thought I had my logic in the switch section correct but maybe I'm just not familiar enough with JS to see my issue.

Code:
    ImportES = app.trustedFunction(function() {

```
var fileName = "/c/Users/jcoleman/Desktop/Endless Slings/Endless Sling Data.txt";
var outputDir = "/c/Users/jcoleman/Desktop/Endless Slings/";
var whichCert = this.getField("PFFSID").value;
var firstThree = whichCert.substr(0,3);
var whichFolder = "0";
var whichCase = whichCert.indexOf("Z");

var err = 0;
var idx = 0;
while (err == 0) {
err = this.importTextData(fileName, idx);

switch (whichCase) {

case 3: {
    if (0 < firstThree && firstThree <49)
        whichFolder = "z1-49/";
    else if (49 < firstThree && firstThree <99)
        whichFolder = "z50-99/";
    else if (99 < firstThree && firstThree <149) 
        whichFolder = "z100-149/";
    else if (149 < firstThree && firstThree <199) 
        whichFolder = "z150-199/";
    else if (199 < firstThree && firstThree <249) 
        whichFolder = "z200-249/";
    else if (249 < firstThree && firstThree <299) 
        whichFolder = "z250-299/";
    else if (299 < firstThree && firstThree <349) 
        whichFolder = "z300-349/";
    else if (349 < firstThree && firstThree <399) 
        whichFolder = "z350-399/";
    else if (399 < firstThree && firstThree <449) 
        whichFolder = "z400-449/";
    else if (449 < firstThree && firstThree <499) 
        whichFolder = "z450-499/";
    else if (499 < firstThree && firstThree <549) 
        whichFolder = "z500-549/";
    else if (549 < firstThree && firstThree <599) 
        whichFolder = "z550-599/";
    else if (599 < firstThree && firstThree <649) 
        whichFolder = "z600-649/";
    else if (649 < firstThree && firstThree <699) 
        whichFolder = "z650-699/";
    else if (699 < firstThree && firstThree <749) 
        whichFolder = "z700-749/";
    else if (749 < firstThree && firstThree <799) 
        whichFolder = "z750-799/";
    else if (799 < firstThree && firstThree <849) 
        whichFolder = "z800-849/";
    else if (849 < firstThree && firstThree <899) 
        whichFolder = "z850-899/";
    else if (899 < firstThree && firstThree <949) 
        whichFolder = "z900-949/";
    else if (949 < firstThree && firstThree <999) 
        whichFolder = "z950-999/";
    break;
}



case -1: {
    if (0 < firstThree && firstThree <49)
        whichFolder = "1-49/";
    else if (49 < firstThree && firstThree <99)
        whichFolder = "50-99/";
    else if (99 < firstThree && firstThree <149) 
        whichFolder = "100-149/";
    else if (149 < firstThree && firstThree <199) 
        whichFolder = "150-199/";
    else if (199 < firstThree && firstThree <249) 
        whichFolder = "200-249/";
    else if (249 < firstThree && firstThree <299) 
        whichFolder = "250-299/";
    else if (299 < firstThree && firstThree <349) 
        whichFolder = "300-349/";
    else if (349 < firstThree && firstThree <399) 
        whichFolder = "350-399/";
    else if (399 < firstThree && firstThree <449) 
        whichFolder = "400-449/";
    else if (449 < firstThree && firstThree <499) 
        whichFolder = "450-499/";
    else if (499 < firstThree && firstThree <549) 
        whichFolder = "500-549/";
    else if (549 < firstThree && firstThree <599) 
        whichFolder = "550-599/";
    else if (599 < firstThree && firstThree <649) 
        whichFolder = "600-649/";
    else if (649 < firstThree && firstThree <699) 
        whichFolder = "650-699/";
    else if (699 < firstThree && firstThree <749) 
        whichFolder = "700-749/";
    else if (749 < firstThree && firstThree <799) 
        whichFolder = "750-799/";
    else if (799 < firstThree && firstThree <849) 
        whichFolder = "800-849/";
    else if (849 < firstThree && firstThree <899) 
        whichFolder = "850-899/";
    else if (899 < firstThree && firstThree <949) 
        whichFolder = "900-949/";
    else if (949 < firstThree && firstThree <999) 
        whichFolder = "950-999/";
}
}



if (err == -1)
    app.alert("Error: Cannot Open File");
else if (err == -2)
    app.alert("Error: Cannot Load Data");
else if (err == 1)
    app.alert("Warning: User Cancelled File Select");
else if (err == 2)
    app.alert("Warning: User Cancelled Row Select");
else if (err == 3)
    app.alert("Warning: Missing Data");
else if (err == 0) {
    this.saveAs(outputDir + whichFolder + "ES-" + this.getField("PFFSID").value + ".pdf"); 
    idx++;
}
}
});

// menu item
app.addMenuItem({
cName: "ImportES",
cUser: "Import Endless Slings",
cParent: "Edit",
cExec: "ImportES()",
cEnable: "event.rc = (event.target != null);",
nPos: 1
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to edit my OP. After pulling my code apart to test individual pieces I found out that my variable whichCert isn't pulled from the form as a string and therefor the substr will not work on it.I've tried a few things to get around it by converting it to a string with toString and just by using valueAsString but none of it is working. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue with help from a different forum. It was my variables and how I never let the while loop define them, I had only declared them at the top so the loop just saw it as a constant value which was the first record being imported.

Maintain a balanced diet and don't neglect your fruits and variables, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a context problem. I can't test this without your files but here's what I think should work...

```
var ImportES = app.trustedFunction(function(doc) {
    var fileName = "/c/Users/jcoleman/Desktop/Endless Slings/Endless Sling Data.txt";
    var outputDir = "/c/Users/jcoleman/Desktop/Endless Slings/";
    var whichCert = doc.getField("PFFSID").value;
    var firstThree = whichCert.substr(0,3);
    var whichFolder = "0";
    var whichCase = whichCert.indexOf("Z");

    var err = 0;
    var idx = 0;
    while (err == 0) {
    err = doc.importTextData(fileName, idx);

    switch (whichCase) {

    case 3: {
        if (0 < firstThree && firstThree <49)
            whichFolder = "z1-49/";
        else if (49 < firstThree && firstThree <99)
            whichFolder = "z50-99/";
        else if (99 < firstThree && firstThree <149) 
            whichFolder = "z100-149/";
        else if (149 < firstThree && firstThree <199) 
            whichFolder = "z150-199/";
        else if (199 < firstThree && firstThree <249) 
            whichFolder = "z200-249/";
        else if (249 < firstThree && firstThree <299) 
            whichFolder = "z250-299/";
        else if (299 < firstThree && firstThree <349) 
            whichFolder = "z300-349/";
        else if (349 < firstThree && firstThree <399) 
            whichFolder = "z350-399/";
        else if (399 < firstThree && firstThree <449) 
            whichFolder = "z400-449/";
        else if (449 < firstThree && firstThree <499) 
            whichFolder = "z450-499/";
        else if (499 < firstThree && firstThree <549) 
            whichFolder = "z500-549/";
        else if (549 < firstThree && firstThree <599) 
            whichFolder = "z550-599/";
        else if (599 < firstThree && firstThree <649) 
            whichFolder = "z600-649/";
        else if (649 < firstThree && firstThree <699) 
            whichFolder = "z650-699/";
        else if (699 < firstThree && firstThree <749) 
            whichFolder = "z700-749/";
        else if (749 < firstThree && firstThree <799) 
            whichFolder = "z750-799/";
        else if (799 < firstThree && firstThree <849) 
            whichFolder = "z800-849/";
        else if (849 < firstThree && firstThree <899) 
            whichFolder = "z850-899/";
        else if (899 < firstThree && firstThree <949) 
            whichFolder = "z900-949/";
        else if (949 < firstThree && firstThree <999) 
            whichFolder = "z950-999/";
        break;
    }



    case -1: {
        if (0 < firstThree && firstThree <49)
            whichFolder = "1-49/";
        else if (49 < firstThree && firstThree <99)
            whichFolder = "50-99/";
        else if (99 < firstThree && firstThree <149) 
            whichFolder = "100-149/";
        else if (149 < firstThree && firstThree <199) 
            whichFolder = "150-199/";
        else if (199 < firstThree && firstThree <249) 
            whichFolder = "200-249/";
        else if (249 < firstThree && firstThree <299) 
            whichFolder = "250-299/";
        else if (299 < firstThree && firstThree <349) 
            whichFolder = "300-349/";
        else if (349 < firstThree && firstThree <399) 
            whichFolder = "350-399/";
        else if (399 < firstThree && firstThree <449) 
            whichFolder = "400-449/";
        else if (449 < firstThree && firstThree <499) 
            whichFolder = "450-499/";
        else if (499 < firstThree && firstThree <549) 
            whichFolder = "500-549/";
        else if (549 < firstThree && firstThree <599) 
            whichFolder = "550-599/";
        else if (599 < firstThree && firstThree <649) 
            whichFolder = "600-649/";
        else if (649 < firstThree && firstThree <699) 
            whichFolder = "650-699/";
        else if (699 < firstThree && firstThree <749) 
            whichFolder = "700-749/";
        else if (749 < firstThree && firstThree <799) 
            whichFolder = "750-799/";
        else if (799 < firstThree && firstThree <849) 
            whichFolder = "800-849/";
        else if (849 < firstThree && firstThree <899) 
            whichFolder = "850-899/";
        else if (899 < firstThree && firstThree <949) 
            whichFolder = "900-949/";
        else if (949 < firstThree && firstThree <999) 
            whichFolder = "950-999/";
    }
}



if (err == -1)
    app.alert("Error: Cannot Open File");
else if (err == -2)
    app.alert("Error: Cannot Load Data");
else if (err == 1)
    app.alert("Warning: User Cancelled File Select");
else if (err == 2)
    app.alert("Warning: User Cancelled Row Select");
else if (err == 3)
    app.alert("Warning: Missing Data");
else if (err == 0) {
    this.saveAs(outputDir + whichFolder + "ES-" + this.getField("PFFSID").value + ".pdf"); 
    idx++;
}
}
});

// menu item
app.addMenuItem({
cName: "ImportES",
cUser: "Import Endless Slings",
cParent: "Edit",
cExec: "ImportES(this)",
cEnable: "event.rc = (event.target != null);",
nPos: 1
});
```

Comment: I actually figured out my issue with help from another forum and totally forgot I had posted here as well! My issue was the variables and how I didn't define them within the While loop, I had only declared them at the start so the while loop never changed them. Thanks for the reply, though! I'll edit my OP.